# Is there a way to dynamically change the axes on final Dashboard view for QlikView and Tableau just like how Google Motion Charts allow it?

Tags: data-visualization, google-visualization, qlikview, tableau-api

Google Motion Charts allow the end-user to alter the x-axis and y-axis variables on the final product via a drop-down menu.

Is it possible to implement the same for QlikView or Tableau?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is. In Tableau, one would use a Drop-down box with a list of the variables. Instead of putting an actual variable (we call it a dimension) on the chart, you would add a field which is the result of a calculation.

That calculation "chooses" the dimension/variable to display based on the selection in the parameter drop-down. It's fairly straight forward:

```
IF [Parameter Name] = "My First Variable" Then [Dimension 1] 
ELSEIF Parameter Name] = "My First Variable" Then [Dimension 2]
ELSE [Dimension 3]
END
```

Comment: There is also a case statement in Tableau's calculation language in case you find that more readable than a list of if/else clauses.